# How do I get a recursive list of the full, bare paths of all files modified since a given date?

Tags: windows, powershell, file-management

I need to get a list of all files, matching a given mask, in all subdirectories from a given path, which have been modified since a given date. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I posted this question so I can Google it if I need it later.  If you have an even better way, feel free to add additional answers!

#### To get all files modified since n days ago:

```
(Get-ChildItem -Path C:\MyPath -Recurse -Filter *.sql |?{ $_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-180)})|foreach{$_.FullName} > changes.txt
```

where 180 is the # of days ago (where -1 is yesterday), and where *.sql is the file mask that matches the files I need, and where C:\MyPath is the root directory to recurse through.

#### To get all files modified since a specific date:

```
(Get-ChildItem -Path C:\MyPath -Recurse -Filter *.sql |?{ $_.LastWriteTime -gt '4/23/2019'})|foreach{$_.FullName} > changes.txt
```

where I need files modified since 4/23/2019 at midnight local time, and where *.sql is the file mask that matches the files I need, and where C:\MyPath is the root directory to recurse through.

These both give me a list in this format:

```
C:\MyPath\file001.sql
C:\MyPath\subdir\file002.sql
```